# Argument 'cotroller' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my HTML file

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>CBIR</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/AngularCotroller.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/ApiCallService.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="AppController">
         <div class="form-group row">
            <button id="btnGetKey" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="btnGetKey()">Get Key</button>
            <p> {{message}}</p>
        </div>


        <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</script>
```

This is AngularController.js file

```
var angularmodule = angular.module('App', []);

angularmodule.controller('AppController', function ($scope, $http, ApiCall)      {
//Intital message value
$scope.message = "Don't Give up";
$scope.btnGetkey = function () {

    var result = ApiCall.GetKeyFromServer().success(function (data) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(JSON.parse(data));
        $scope.message = data;
        $scope.message = "123123123";
    });
};


});
```

This  is ApiServiceCall file

```
angularmodule.service('ApiCall', ['$http', function ($http) 
{
var result;

// This is used for calling get methods from web api
this.GetKeyFromServer = function () {
    result = $http.get('http://localhost:8090/CBIR/checkReturn').success(function (data, status) {
        result = (data);
    }).error(function () {
        alert("Something went wrong");
    });
    return result;
};

}]);
```

When i load the index file  Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'AppController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/ng/areq?p0=AppController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
i get this error. Please help

Comment: my first guess would be that you cant instantiate the controller, because it uses your ApiCall service, and that is wrongly registered. Try `App.service('ApiCall'...` instead. Let me know whether that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You alias one parameter, but the actual function uses three:

```
['$scope', function ($scope, $http, ApiCall)
```

You need either to specify all of them, like this:

```
['$scope', '$http', 'ApiCall', function ($scope, $http, ApiCall)
```

or if you're not going to minimize your code, just use:

```
function ($scope, $http, ApiCall)
```

---

As @Slytherin suggested, the other error you have is in your service file:

- you have a typo: `AnguarModule` != `angular.module`
- and even if it wasn't a typo, you're reinstantiating your module, instead of referencing it (the difference being the second parameter - [see the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval))

Comment: Didnt even notice that. Upvoting

Comment: @Slytherin You are right about the service as well.

Comment: Hmmm, should be fine now. Are you sure you don't have a typo, like you have in the question title and in the script src? And where is `App` defined?

Comment: Hmmm, seems fine now. Can you write it as a snippet here, or use Plunker?